# How to verify, JavaFX 2.0 uses directx 9 on a XP box?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx, directx-9, javafx-2

I have a Windows XP installation on a Computer with a Intel 945 Chipset, which I want to run a  JavaFX 2.0 App on. It has DirectX 9.29 installed, but it does not seem to utilize it, as the processor load is very high (70-100% for some hundret points refreshed 2-4 times a second. ok it's a weak device, but that's to high...)

Is there a way to verify Prism utilizes the directx rendering?

update: I have installed the latest drivers, i have moved to windows 7 embedded which uses DirectX 11. When I start dxdiag.exe it tells me DirectX (DirectDraw, Direct3D, AGP Texture Acceleration) is enabled. But JavaFX 2.0 is horrible slow and only utilizes the CPU and not the GPU.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to support Intel 945 Chipsets in JavaFX 2.0 Hardware Accelerated. The Problem is it needs Pixel Shader 3.0 to utilize hardware acceleration, [but the Chipset only supports PS 2.0.](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-014257.htm).

You can find more details on wy it not uses hardware acceleration with following commands:

`set NWT_TRACE_LEVEL=4`
`java -Dprism.verbose=true`

Comment: Thanks. With these I was able to see that the NVidia GPU is actually being used on my Mac, for JavaFX (don't know why it's so slow though).

Comment: Took me ages to figure that one out. Belive me. Flipping between forums, bug trackers, hardware specifications,....

Comment: Yep, these are unsupported and undocumented command line switches which may be dropped at any time - still useful though . . .

Answer (score 0):

Check JavaFX 2.0 graphics card requirements here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements/jfxpub-system_requirements.htm